# OpenDNS name servers

Tags: dns, tcpip, opendns

I'm using the below open DNS name servers which I got from a friend. Are they trustable?

```
4.2.2.1, 4.2.2.2, 4.2.2.3, 4.2.2.4, 4.2.2.5, 4.2.2.6
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are open DNS servers - i.e. they're on the public internet.  They [belong to Level 3](http://forums.techguy.org/networking/277805-what-4-2-2-1-a.html) so are probably safe to use.

[OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) (note no space) is another DNS provider which has different addresses for it's public servers, which are in [harrymc's post](https://superuser.com/questions/73427/opendns-name-servers/73429#73429).

Answer (score 5):

According to [opendns.com](http://www.opendns.com/support/article/197):

> OpenDNS nameserver IP addresses are:
>
> 208.67.220.220
>   208.67.222.222
>
> Some routers and devices need a third
>   or fourth nameserver IP address. Use
>   these if necessary (identical service
>   to the original two):
>
> 208.67.220.222
>   208.67.222.220

Answer (score 3):

They have nothing to do with OpenDNS (see Dave Webb's post) and, since they are open recursive name servers, they should **not** be trusted:

- risk of being shut down at every moment, because they can be used for amplification attacks (see [RFC 5358](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5358.txt))
- much higher risk of poisoning through the Kaminsky weakness (since a prerequisite of the Kaminsky attack is the ability to **use** the name server).